# Show notification only if previous one has been canceled

Tags: android, notifications

I'm creating a very simple application for myself. Basically, it gives me a certain notification exactly every 2 hours.

The problem is when I don't "check" the notification for 2 hours and the next notification is supposed to come around. It sends a notification even though another notification already exists.

I'm simply sending  notifications with NotificationManager.

Is there a way to check if previous notification already exists and only send another one if it doesn't?

Comment: So what's the problem with the notification already exists? Is it multiple notifications in the tray? Sound/vibrate even if they already have a notification? Something else?

Comment: The sound/vibration is the only problem. Let's say I go to bed and sleep for 8 hours. It will give me a notification and therefore sound/vibrate 4 times while I'm asleep.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you are using the same notification id (so that only one notification appears in the notification tray), you can use [setOnlyAlertOnce(true)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setOnlyAlertOnce(boolean)) to ensure that sound/vibrate only plays the very first time a notification is posted and not when an existing notification is updated.